# Allow snmpd to read /proc/net/* when running a grsecurity kernel and the grsec_proc group

Tags: linux, security, snmp

I have rented a VPS from OVH (the Kimsufi 2G), and I'm having troubles getting snmpd to work correctly.

The box is a Debian Squeeze running an OVH custom kernel:

```
root@vps:~# uname -a
Linux vps 2.6.38.2-grsec-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #2 SMP Thu Aug 25 16:40:22 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The problem is `snmpd` is spamming the `syslog` with `cannot open /proc/net/*`:

```
root@vps:~# tail -f /var/log/syslog
Feb  8 23:57:38 vps snmpd[32481]: cannot open /proc/net/dev ...
Feb  8 23:57:53 vps snmpd[32481]: cannot open /proc/net/dev ...
Feb  8 23:58:01 vps /USR/SBIN/CRON[3074]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 39 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
Feb  8 23:58:08 vps snmpd[32481]: cannot open /proc/net/dev ...
Feb  8 23:58:23 vps snmpd[32481]: cannot open /proc/net/dev ...
Feb  8 23:58:38 vps snmpd[32481]: cannot open /proc/net/snmp ...
Feb  8 23:58:38 vps snmpd[32481]: cannot open /proc/net/dev ...
Feb  8 23:58:53 vps snmpd[32481]: cannot open /proc/net/dev ...
Feb  8 23:59:01 vps /USR/SBIN/CRON[3117]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 39 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
Feb  8 23:59:08 vps snmpd[32481]: cannot open /proc/net/dev ...
```

It seems the problem is caused by the `grsecurity` kernel patch, as stated [here](http://forums.grsecurity.net/viewtopic.php?t=2048) and [here](http://blog.kevin-k.com/2009-06-22/snmpd-cannot-open-procnetdev-or-procnetsnmp.html).

But there's no `grsec_proc` group, so I can't change the group `snmpd` runs as, as mentioned in the first link, and recompiling and installing a new kernel is not an option, as I'm not expert enough.

Is there another way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the *proc group* in the `grsec` kernel config:

```
#
# Filesystem Protections
#
[…]
CONFIG_GRKERNSEC_PROC_USERGROUP=y
CONFIG_GRKERNSEC_PROC_GID=1005
[…]
```

Then you have to put the user you want to have access to `/proc` in the group with `group-id:1005`.

Comment: Does this mean I have to recompile the kernel?!